# SetFocus run-time error from label's Click event

Tags: vba, ms-access

On a form I have a bound text box that, if a user enters data into this text box, the user must enter 7 characters, only. To check for the required 7 character length, I have the following code in the text box’s AfterUpdate event:

```
        If Len(myTextBox) <> 7 Then
            MsgBox "Entry must be 7 characters long”
            myTextBox.Undo
            myTextBox = Null
            differentTextBox.SetFocus
            myTextBox.SetFocus
        End If
```

All works as intended under all circumstances, except one:
If the user enters less than 7 characters in myTextBox, then clicks on a form’s label which has the following in the on Click event:

```
        myLabel.Visible = False
        differentTextBox.SetFocus
```

I get Run-Time Error 2110: Microsoft Access can’t move the focus to the control differentTextBox.

If I tab out of myTextBox when it contains less than 7 characters, I get my MsgBox message, myTextBox is blanked (set to null), and the cursor remains in myTextBox to allow the user to reenter. This same desired result also happens when myTextBox contains less than 7 characters and the user clicks to a different text box or control on the form.

I tried the code in the label’s click event (above) in a command button click event, and no error.

I can’t figure out why a run-time error is occurring **only** when the user clicks on a label with a setfocus command.

The label’s on Click event also otherwise functions as desired, except when clicked on as described above.

I’ve also tried moving the myTextBox code from AfterUpdate to BeforeUpdate and on Exit, no luck.

Comment: BeforeUpdate is the appropriate event for data validation. Use Cancel = True. Setting to Null is not needed and can be an issue. Why do you set focus to differentTextBox then to myTextBox?

Comment: You want to set label that is clicked not visible? Code tries to change focus to differentTextBox which causes MyTextBox to try to save value which fails because of invalid data. Can't set focus to differentTextBox because MyTextBox cannot lose focus. Why set focus to differentTextBox?

Answer (score 0):

It most likely will be a missing or double keystroke, so don't erase the textbox, but leave it to be edited.

Also, use the `BeforeUpdate` event:

```vb
Cancel = Len(Nz(Me!myTextBox.Value)) <> 7

If Cancel Then
    MsgBox "Entry must be 7 characters long."
End If
```